# Extract Data Without Quotes in iMacros

Tags: firefox, imacros

How to extract data without quotes in iMacros? The following code can remove comma, but still give me quotes sign.

```
SET !VAR6 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; s.replace(',', '');")
```

I am using FF broser. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove **'** from your text together with the **,**? Your code keeps the quotes, because you don't do anything to replace them. You can use

```
SET !VAR6 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; s.replace(/[,']/g, '');")
```

to replace every occurence of either character. Read up on [regular expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and on [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to tweak this if it's not precisely what you want.